# why my DVD and USB device can not be read by bios?

Tags: bios

I can use my usb drive and DVD drive to read and write when I enter into Windows 7. 
When ENTERING into bios by pressing F8, in the boot menu, I can not see the USD and DVD device, what is the matter with my motherboard?  The type of motherboard is asus H81M .

Comment: Do you actually have a disk in the drive / a USB stick inserted when you enter the boot menu?

Comment: What @JasonC said, but also make sure that you have the USB and CD/DVD devices enabled as bootable devices in your BIOS.

Comment: yes,there is surely a disk in the drive / a USB stick inserted when i enter the boot menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what is default mode: UEFI or Legacy:

1. You will need probably to disable `Secure Boot` in the BIOS

[image]
[image]

2. You may also need `disable Quick Boot`

[image]

3. In general you will always need to `Enable USB Boot` and select `First Boot Device` (USB disk or CD/DVD)

[image]
[image]

or, for example,

[image]

4. Specifically to your H81M mainboard you will probably need to pass instructions form page 29 from this Manual http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/H81M-A/E8599_H81M-Series.pdf
   [image]

Also you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8Ml1IbVp-8)

Comment: You shouldn't have to disable secure boot to boot to a bootable disk.

Comment: 1.when i close the quick boot,the bios can read my DVD and USB.

Comment: 2.i find that secure boot can not be changed .